# What's the golgari stance on an "earth god" like Gaia?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-lore

From my understanding of Golgari philosophy Gaia would at least not be a problem/conflict. But in fact be a great symbol for what they believe in in the first place.

Reasoning: Things living and dying is part just part of Gaia's existence. Like the metabolism of god.

Is there any canon material on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is planes are all separate, and each plane has it's own beliefs, systems, and in many cases actual godly figures and gods. So while Gaia, spelled as Gaea within magic cards such as [Gaea's Cradle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGaea%27s%5d%2b%5bCradle%5d), does exist within the planes of blind eternities, she exists tied to the plane of Dominaria and doesn't actually exist on Ravnica. The closest thing to it as far as a spirit of the plane itself is [Soul of Ravnica](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20of%20Ravnica%5d).

As for the idea of what a godess like Gaea would represent, there would be no conflict there with the Golgari - Gaea represents the natural world, including the cycle of life and death, something which is actually pretty core to the Golgari.

This is based mostly on my own understanding of this though, as again, Gaea does not exist as far as Ravnica is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

**Ravnica’s Worldsoul**

Ravnica does actually have a “Gaia” type entity but sadly they are sometimes at odds with it. Mat'Selesnya the voice and song behind the Selesnya Guild is Ravnica’s Worldsoul. This fact is not directly referenced in the cards themselves but the best representation would be: [Song of the Worldsoul](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Worldsoul)
It is more directly referred to as the world soul in the original Ravnica Trilogy novels**, in the Return to Ravnica/Dragon’s Maze Story, hinted at in War of the Spark when Nissa ‘spoke’ to Mat'Selesnya, and further reinforced through several short stories and even in Dack Fayden’s comics.

** *Return to Ravnica does have six~ish cards which mention it but they are kind of cryptic without further context.*

** *The original Ravnica novels predate the term Worldsoul, describing her originally as "the very Heart and Soul of Ravnica itself" But she got a title change shortly after Alara.*

**How the Golgari Deal with “Gaia”**

With difficulty. Mat'Selesnya was stated to be a more intune with nature in the past as the Gruul Clans also recall a time when they revered her amongst their pantheon. However in moderns time Ms. Selesnya is more focused on not just it’s people being harmonious but also how manufactured stone and concrete blends with natural trees and life. This is a point of view the Gruul are not in favor of, and truth be told the Golgari don’t really care for either. This implies that as the world-city-Ravnica grew and grew it changed the very nature of the Worldsoul itself, it’s people changing it’s point of view.

The novels *Ravnica (novel), Dissension (novel), and The Gathering Storm (Online Story)*, show that the Golgori actually get along with the Selesnyains more than any of the other guilds. In some rare cases the Elves even have cross-guild children with each other. What is really keeping the two guilds from merging is the fact that while the Golgori believe the Selesnyas are doing "the right thing", they also think they are too soft. Which is where most of their guild conflicts come from. In addition many of the subfactions within the Golgori prefer there to be a Ranking Hierarchy so they can scheme and plot for more power. Something Golgori leaders have openly admitted in the past, and a structure is something the Selesnyas lack.

**The Soul of…**

The “Soul of..” cards are a bane to my existence as they constantly confuse people.
As stated bluntly by a snarky Mr. Rosewater. Here:
https://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/186943031108/mark-since-we-were-talking-about-the-soul-cycle

Ravnica’s Worldsoul (Mat'Selesnya) is not the same thing as the “[Soul of Ravnica](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20of%20Ravnica)”

To further drive this home:
https://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/105672907948/i-remember-that-you-once-described-theros-as-being

The design team intentionally used "incorrect colors" for some of the Souls Of (Theros vs Zendikar in this example) so they could complete the color cycle. Keep in mind the main focus for the Soul Of cards were the play pattern for the Draft format first, lore came secondary- Although truly lore not at all because there is no lore associated with this cycle of cards, not even flavor text.

**Other**

It should be noted that many of the other Ravnican guilds are dubious or out right disbelieve that Mat'Selesnya is the Worldsoul or "God of Ravnica" because it’s teaching clashes with their own beliefs. The Golgori for the most part know exactly who she is, and choose to only partly follow her, in their own way.

The Primal Gruul nature Gods (Mentioned in Guildpact Novel, and RtR Stories) were finally shown creditability with [Ilharg, the Raze-Boar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ilharg%2C%20the%20Raze-Boar) showing that there are other nature gods out there, but only one confirmed at the moment. To date the Golgori have no comment on them.

Of note: The parallel between Gaia and Mat'Selesnya is actually pretty strong since in recent years with the *The Brothers' War* online stories the Dominaria’s Worldsoul was confirmed to be Gaia (or Gaea). Although that has add some contractions to older lore, so don’t dig too deep into that.